# how do i add all js array objects to one string?

Tags: javascript, json, discord

I want to use a JSON and add all of the **IDs** into a string, but I am having some trouble.
I am fairly new to working with JSON objects, so please explain how it works if you have any ideas.

I want to convert this:

```
let users = [
  {"id":"24317318904217xxxx","name":"person 1"},
  {"id":"69336408842371xxxx","name":"person 2"}
]

var str = `ID\'s `
```

To something like this:

```
`ID's: <@24317318904217xxxx>, <@69336408842371xxxx>`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Note that what is shown is a javascript array of objects and actually has nothing to do with JSON which is a string data format

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, good point, I'll edit to show my attempts so far! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method in javascript to create this structure.

Basically, you create an array with use template string then push it inside your array variable and modify it.

1 - Create an array with use your data

```
str = users.map(user => `@${user.id}`)
```

2 - Add 'ID's' text into your variable and use [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to convert your data as a string

```
str = `ID\s ${str.join(', ')}`
```

Have a nice and productive day!

Full Code :

```js
let users = [{
    "id": "24317318904217xxxx",
    "name": "person 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "69336408842371xxxx",
    "name": "person 2"
  }
]

str = users.map(user => `<@${user.id}>`)
str = `ID\s ${str.join(', ')}`

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are new to JS, you can get started with a simple for loop over the users [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) like this:

```
let users = [
  {"id":"24317318904217xxxx","name":"person 1"},
  {"id":"69336408842371xxxx","name":"person 2"}
]

let str = "ID's: ";

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    str += `<@${users[i].id}>`;
    if (i < users.length - 1)
        str += ", ";
}
```

To access the i-th object in the array (0-indexed) use `users[i]`;

To access an object's 'id' property simply use `object.id`. Same with name and all other properties.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

The string concatenation might look a bit weird to you, it's a string template see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

The other answer uses `map` and `join` which you can read more about on the array mdn article. I highly recommend you reading into it, as Javascript code often uses these functions, but might need so getting used to for people who only ever written iterative code.

If you have any other questions feel free to ask in the comments!